# Why does “while(true)” without “Thread.sleep” cause 100% CPU usage on Linux but not on Windows?

Tags: java, linux, windows, multithreading, cpu-usage

I have created a simple program in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) 
        ;
}
```

If I run this on a Linux machine, it shows 100% CPU usage, but doesn't cause the OS to appear slow.  However, if I run the exact same code on Windows, it only shows about 20% CPU usage.

I am using Oracle JRE on Windows and OpenJDK 6 on Linux.

I'm wondering if Windows' scheduler preempt threads randomly and Linux's doesn't?

Comment: It is depend upon Operating System Task Scheduling.

Comment: how many cores do you have? Windows task manager report 100% when ALL cores are busy. Does your linux tool do something similar, or does it report 100% for 1 core's worth of work, and when all cores are busy, it's `100*N cores %`?

Comment: I have 4 cores and on linux I use system monitor tool

Comment: @Quoi Not really. If that program is all that is running, then the thread will run without interruption on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

By default, `top` on Linux runs in so-called IRIX mode, while the Windows Task Manager does not. Let's say you have 4 cores:

- With IRIX mode on, 1 fully utilized core is 100% and 4 cores are 400%.
- With IRIX mode off, 1 fully utilized core is 25% and 4 cores are 100%.

This means that by default, `top` on Linux will show an infinite loop as ~100% and Windows will show it as ~25%, and it means exactly the same thing.

You can toggle IRIX mode while `top` is running with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. This will make the numbers match up.

Comment: Yup - on a '4+4' i7, (hyperthreading), one trivial CPU loop comes out at about 17-18%.

Comment: Why does the answerer though has 150UPs still his score is 700's... is it SO bug?? :-/

Comment: @uDaY, because there is a max of 200 rep a day, any upvotes after that are not counted, accepted anwers still will be.

Comment: @thatotherguy When exactly to hit shift-I to toggle ? While top is running ?